# Delphi: switch bands of CoolBar

Tags: delphi, toolbar, switch-statement

[image]

What is an efficient way to change buttons (bands) in the CoolBar (the red rectangle) while switching among items in the TreeView (the purple rectangle). I want to use one set of buttons for every item in the list view.

Thanks for help and advices!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd create the CoolBands I'd need and assign each to the Data pointer of the TTreeNode for which it is to be used. Then in the TreeView's OnChanging handler, I'd "remember" the TreeNode that is currently selected and switch visibility on the CoolBands in the OnChange handler:

```
procedure TProbeerForm.TreeView1Changing(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode;
  var AllowChange: Boolean);
begin
  FOldNode := TreeView1.Selected;
end;

procedure TProbeerForm.TreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  TCoolBand(FOldNode.Data).Visible := False;
  TCoolBand(Node.Data).Visible := True;
end;
```

Comment: Nice idea! `OnChanging` could be used for switching the visibility too, but `OnChange` might be a better place. Alternatively `Data` could be the index instead of the pointer.

Comment: Actually, I have never used cool bands myself. I did toy around with them in the Delphi 7 era, but found them to be buggy. Ever since I have been perfectly happy with ordinary toolbars. Do you think I should reconsider?

Comment: @Andreas: There's an old saying: let well alone. :)

Comment: @Andreas: I never use them either. Not in the normal sense that is. I have used a coolbar to hold an ordinary toolbar on a panel on a tabsheet because otherwise theming/glass/etc would paint the toolbar as completely black... Putting a coolbar between the tabsheet/panel and the toolbar changes when / the manner in which the toolbar is painted and prevents the problem.